# Azure Mobile Services Toast Notification

Tags: push-notification, toast, mpns, azure-mobile-services

Any ideas on why I can't see the toast notification in any phone? I can successfully receive and see the tile flip notifications but not for toast.

In the logs I can see the toast as received status, I'm using a script to send the notification.

And in the app I can't catch anything in the ShellToastNotificationReceived event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I did two things: restarted the phone and deployed in release, I think the former was the problem :S